# Table view is returning only 1 section instead 2. How solve that?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm fetching data from a Realm database and I want to populate a tableview with 2 sections: Autobots and Decepticons. But section property from TableView is returning just the position 0 from the array. Please help me, Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


     let sections = ["Autobots","Decepticons"]
    var autobotsNames : [String] = []
    var decepticonsNames : [String] = []
    var allTransformersNames = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
        let transformers = Transformers()
        let transformersData =  transformers.TransformersData()

            for data in transformersData {
                if data.group == "A" {
                    autobotsNames.append(data.name)
                }
                else {
                    decepticonsNames.append(data.name)
                }
            }
        allTransformersNames.append(autobotsNames)
        allTransformersNames.append(decepticonsNames)

        print(autobotsNames)
        print(decepticonsNames)
        print(allTransformersNames)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.allTransformersNames[section].count
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Transformers", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.allTransformersNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

 }
```

[Print Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRB2D.png)

[TableView showing 1 section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdtzJ.png)

Comment: can you print sections value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView only displays one section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659201/uitableview-only-displays-one-section)